# Executable 3 times slower on Windows (Mingw64) than Linux

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

I'm developping a game engine which is about 3-4 times slower on Windows than on Linux.
I tried to profile the application and I don't see particular problem except that everything seems more slow on Windows.
I extracted a very small part of the application. I compile it with `g++ -O3 perf.cpp` and execute as follows: `a.exe 500000000`. Here are the results:

- Linux: 10 sec (mean of 5 executions): g++ 8.2 [also tested with g++ 7.3]
- Windows: 27 sec (mean of 5 executions): g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0 [also tested with g++ 7.1]

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

struct Vector{
    float X, Y, Z;

    Vector(float X, float Y, float Z) : X(X), Y(Y), Z(Z){}

    Vector vector(const Vector &target) const{
        return Vector(target.X - X, target.Y - Y, target.Z - Z);
    }

    float dotProduct(const Vector &v) const{
        return (X*v.X + Y*v.Y + Z*v.Z);
    }
};

float compute(const std::vector<Vector> &v){
    Vector vec1 = v[0].vector(v[2]);
    Vector vec2 = v[1].vector(v[0]);
    return vec1.dotProduct(vec2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned int loopMax = atoi(argv[1]);

    Vector va(1.5f, 3.0f, 8.0f*loopMax);
    Vector vb(1.2f, 2.3f, 11.0f*loopMax);
    Vector vc(8.2f, 5.0f, 12.0f*loopMax);

    auto frameStartTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    float res = 0.0f;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<loopMax; ++i)
    {       
        res += compute({va, vb, vc});
    }

    auto frameEndTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto diffTimeMicroSeconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(frameEndTime - frameStartTime).count();

    std::cout<<"Time: "<<diffTimeMicroSeconds / 1000000.0 <<" sec, res: "<<res<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know that difference for one iteration is ridiculous (<1 us) but it end that my application is 3-4 times slower.

What could explain a such difference? How to find the problem?

Comment: The generated assembly for both cases might be helpful. Also you are supposed to paste code as text in your question.

Comment: Have you tried a different compiler on Windows? I mean, gcc is pretty good, but on Windows the Visual Studio compiler is *often* better.. maybe also try clang.

Comment: In the loop there is a potential heap allocation for the `std::vector<Vector>` argument to `compute`. This could cause OS / standard library implementation dependent performance.

Comment: @eukaryota this is probably it - the heap allocation is guaranteed, only clang can do heap elision nowadays AFAIK.

Comment: Please don't link to code. Post relevant code *in* the question, as *text*.

Comment: How about `-march=native -flto`?

Comment: Thank for you answers. Tested with "-march=native -flto": no difference. Tested with clang: a little worst (31 sec).

Answer (score 3):

Try constructing the argument to `compute` once outside the loop. If the compiler is not eliding the construction of the `std::vector<Vector>` argument, this will most likely cause a heap allocation:

```
std::vector<Vector> arg{va, vb, vc};
for(unsigned int i=0; i<loopMax; ++i)
{       
    res += compute(arg);
}
```

If there is a heap allocation, it will most likely take much more time than the rest of the loop content. How long the heap allocation takes can vary strongly depending on the system and implementation. Removing it will probably improve performance in both cases significantly.

If there is a need to construct the vector everytime in your actual code, then you should consider using a fixed-size array (raw array or std::array), which will not allocate on the heap, but on stack, which is much faster. This seems applicable because you use exactly the three elements in your `compute` implementation.

Should you not know the length of the vector at compile-time *and* need to  reconstruct it everytime in the hot loop, then you *may be* able to reuse the heap-allocated space, more so if you can specify a good guess for the maximal length:

```
std::vector<Vector> arg;
arg.reserve(1000); // Allocate for up to 1000 element
for(unsigned int i=0; i<loopMax; ++i)
{   
    arg.clear();
    arg.push_back(va);
    [...]
    arg.push_back(vn);
    res += compute(arg);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I don't say that code is very optimized. I already try to pass 3 arguments to method instead of vector and difference is huge. What I'm concern about is the execution time difference between Linux and Windows. Can the allocation of memory be 3 times slower on Windows? That seems huge for me. What do you think?

Comment: @OlivierMartin As already said, without seeing the assembly generated, it is hard to tell. The compiler may be responsible for the difference as well. I don't know whether 3 times difference is reasonable, but it doesn't sound too surprising to me. You are effectively just benchmarking the allocation call. What do you mean by `already try to pass 3 arguments to method instead of vector`? You are still heap allocating with `compute({va, vb, vc})` though, because this is a shorthand for constructing a new argument of the function parameter type with the given initializer list.

Comment: I mean, I changed method signature to "compute(const Vector &v0, const Vector &v1, const Vector &v2)" and call method with "compute(va, vb, vc)". I will try to get the assembly (never do that before) and also try another compiler. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @OlivierMartin In that case the heap allocation should be gone and I would expect the results to be much more similar. If that is still not the case, post the new code together with the assembly.

Comment: Without heap allocation, the results are similar. I didn't expect that allocation has so much difference between OS! I will check my whole application and ensure slow allocation can explain the execution time I have. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are using antivirus just on Windows. They intercept syscalls and make your applications slower. I found that the difference between executing with antivirus ON/OFF is negligible when there is almost no dynamic memory allocation (no syscalls), but a lot slower when there is a lot of them.